# С# получить последнюю строчку консоли

Tags: c#, консоль, системное-программирование

Есть допустим вот такой вывод консоли. Это делается при помощи функции, и как мне получить то, что консоль мне возвратило последней строчкой? Не через какую либо функцию для получения данного вывода, а вот мы получили вывод, потом мы взяли и запихнули в переменную последнюю выведенную строку. Так можно вообще?

Вообще задание такое:

> в первом процессе мы выводим строчку в консоль, запускаем второй процесс, и во втором процессе мы считываем строку, которая была записана первым процессом в консоль. Может я не правильно понял задание или просто мудрю с реализацией?

[image: Пример вывода консоли.]

Comment: [Перенаправление ввода-вывода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перенаправление_ввода-вывода)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, второй процесс запущен позже первого, значит вряд ли это перенаправление. Ну или через `first.exe | second.exe`.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-and-writing-blocks-of-characters-and-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Решение

Я покопался и придумал решение.

### Абстракция

Мы будем брать и создавать процесс сервера с 1-м listener'ом. Listener запускается параллельно отн. потока сервера (чтоб можно было прервать работу listener'а). Затем мы запускаем клиент (если в обратном порядке, то клиент выдаст ошибку `TimeoutException`) и появляется соединение, затем сервер берёт, и передаёт сообщение.

### Реализация

Будет 2 проекта: `MessagePublisher` и `MessageReceiver` (или сервер и клиент). Обмен будем производить с помощью библиотеки `System.IO.Pipes.dll` (ссылка #1,2) (включена в платформу `.NET Core App`), а именно *именованные* каналы (ссылка #3), т. к. процессы создаются независимо друг от друга и не получится передать дескриптор анонимного канала.

*Примечание:* пропущены полноценные обработки ошибок (причина: упрощение кода).

#### `MessagePublisher`

*MessagePublisher.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>msgpub</AssemblyName>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

*App.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

namespace MessagePublisher
{
    sealed class App
    {
        string? msg;
        byte[]? serMsg;

        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                if (msg == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Message is not readed");

                return msg;
            }
        }
        public byte[] SerializedMessage
        {
            get
            {
                if (msg == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Message is not readed");

                return serMsg;
            }
        }

        App(ReadOnlySpan<string> args) { }

        static void Main(string[] args) => new App(args.AsSpan()).Run();
        void Run()
        {
            // Пропущена проверка на наличие такого же процесса

            Console.WriteLine("Server is working...");
            Console.WriteLine("Write message");
            Console.Write("> ");
            msg = Console.ReadLine();
            serMsg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msg);

            using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var task = Listen(cts.Token);

            Pause("Press any button to end server work...");

            cts.Cancel();
            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Server resources is disposing...");

            cts.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Server resources disposed");
            Console.WriteLine("Server worked");

            Pause();
        }
        async Task Listen(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            using var stream = new NamedPipeServerStream("msgpub/def", PipeDirection.Out);
            using var bufferOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4);
            var buffer = bufferOwner.Memory.Slice(0, 4);

            Console.WriteLine("Listener is working...");

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listener is waiting for connection...");

                await Task.Run((Action)(() => stream.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancellationToken)));

                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !stream.IsConnected) { }

                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation...");

                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Connection getted");
                Console.WriteLine("Message is sending...");

                BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(buffer.Span, serMsg!.Length);

                stream.Write(buffer.Span);
                stream.Write(serMsg);

                Console.WriteLine("Message sended");
                Console.WriteLine("Listener is disconnecting...");

                if (stream.IsConnected) stream.Disconnect();

                Console.WriteLine("Listener disconnected");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Listener resources is disposing...");

            stream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Listener resources disposed");
            Console.WriteLine("Listener worked");
        }
        void Pause(string? message = null)
        {
            const string defMsg = "Press any button...";

            Console.WriteLine(message ?? defMsg);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        void PrintQuitMessageAndExit(bool isFailed = true)
        {
            Pause();

            Environment.Exit(isFailed ? -1 : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

#### `MessageReceiver`

*MessageReceiver.csproj*

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>msgrcv</AssemblyName>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

*App.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Buffers.Binary;

namespace MessageReceiver
{
    class App
    {
        App(ReadOnlySpan<string> args) { }

        static void Main(string[] args) => new App(args.AsSpan()).Run();
        void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client is working...");

            var stream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "msgpub/def", PipeDirection.In);

            Console.WriteLine("Client is connecting to server...");

            try { stream.Connect(1000); }
            catch (TimeoutException) { PrintErrorMessageAndExit("Connection timed out"); }

            Console.WriteLine("Connection getted");
            Console.WriteLine("Transmission started...");

            Span<byte> encodedBufferLengthBuffer = stackalloc byte[4];

            stream.Read(encodedBufferLengthBuffer);

            var bufferLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(encodedBufferLengthBuffer);

            using var bufferOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferLength);
            var buffer = bufferOwner.Memory.Span.Slice(0, bufferLength);

            if (stream.Read(buffer)!= bufferLength)
                PrintErrorMessageAndExit("Transmition failed");

            Console.WriteLine("Transmission completed");

            var msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {msg}");
            Console.WriteLine("Client resources is disposing...");

            stream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Client resources disposed");
            Console.WriteLine("Client worked");

            Pause();
        }
        void Pause(string? message = null)
        {
            const string defMsg = "Press any button...";

            Console.WriteLine(message ?? defMsg);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        void PrintErrorMessageAndExit(string? message = null)
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                var tempFc = Console.ForegroundColor;

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

                Console.Write("[ERROR]: ");
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                Console.ForegroundColor = tempFc;
            }

            Pause();

            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

## Ссылки

- [Ссылка #1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes?view=netcore-3.1) – `System.IO.Pipes.dll`: Документация (en-US)
- [Ссылка #2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes?view=netcore-3.1) – `System.IO.Pipes.dll`: Документация (ru-RU (машинный перевод))
- [Ссылка #3](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) – Практическое руководство: Использование именованных каналов для взаимодействия между процессами по сети

Comment: Воу. Наверное это слишком круто)
Просто само задание звучит так: процесс А передаёт строку в консоли, а процесс Б, запущенный процессом А,  принимает строку, переданную в консоли процессом А. Получается так, что эти два приложения запущены в одном окне консоли. Или это никак без клиент-серверного приложения? Просто само использование данного способа отправки сообщения будет некорректным относительно самого задания, скорее всего.

Comment: @WasdeDGeek аааааааа.... тогда можно и без Named pipes. что ж вы сразу не сказали!!! тут можно использовать `AnonymousServerPipeStream` и `AnonymousClientPipeStream` они как раз для дочерних процессов и созданы (или для обмена м-ду потоками)

Comment: @WasdeDGeek да. оно будет не корректным, ведь намного проще использовать анонимные трубы, чем именованные( просто если бы вы написали "запуска*ет* 2-й процесс", а не "запуска*ем* 2-й процесс", тогда я бы понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Я сам сперва через анонимные трубы писал, перечитал задание, написал через именованные. оказался неправ(

Comment: @WasdeDGeek мне переписывать через анонимные каналы или как?

Comment: было бы здорово. Потому, что я не особо разбираюсь в клиент серверных прилогах уж темболее на шарпах). 
Я если честно даже бы не подумал, что для того, чтобы получить последнюю выведенную строку в консоли нужно городить клиент-сервер))). 
Может можно как-то проще? Может есть какая-нибудь функция по типу "ГетЛастКонсольСтринг" через какие-нибудь оконные хендлы или что-то подобное? Просто сама дисциплина для которой готовлю задание не подразумевает использование клиент-серверной архитектуры.

Comment: немного не уверен получилось ли вас упомянуть в комментарии выше, по этому на всякий напишу ещё этот

Comment: @WasdeDGeek отвечу по возможности, ведь весь проект надо писать в студии

Comment: @WasdeDGeek смотрите в чём дело. я уже написал код для взаимодействия (и выложил), но работает только в `UseShellExecute = false` (иначе пишет, что invalid handle). Не знаю, как сделать в 2 окна(

Answer (score 0):

*App.cs* (*MessagePublisher.csproj*)

```
using env = Environment;

sealed class App
{
    string msg;

    App(string[] args)
    {
        // mute compiler
        msg = null!;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) => new App(args).Run();
    public void Run()
    {
        const string rcvExePath = "msgrcv.exe";

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher is working...");
            Console.WriteLine("Write message");
            Console.Write("> ");
            msg = Console.ReadLine();
            var encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            var serMsgLen = encoding.GetByteCount(msg);
            var serMsgOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(serMsgLen);
            var serMsg = serMsgOwner.Memory.Slice(0, serMsgLen).Span;
            encoding.GetBytes(msg, serMsg);

            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher resources is initializing...");

            using var stream = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(PipeDirection.Out,
                HandleInheritability.Inheritable); // чтобы можно было передать в дочерний процесс

            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher resources is initialized");
            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver process is launching...");

            using var rcvProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(rcvExePath, stream.GetClientHandleAsString())
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                }
            };
            rcvProcess.Start();

            stream.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();

            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver process is working...");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transmission started...");

                Span<byte> encodedBufferLengthBuffer = stackalloc byte[4];
                BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32BigEndian(encodedBufferLengthBuffer, serMsgLen);

                stream.Write(encodedBufferLengthBuffer);
                stream.Write(serMsg);
                stream.WaitForPipeDrain();

                Console.WriteLine("Transmission completed");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("connect", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            { PrintQuitMessageAndExit("Transmission aborted"); return; }

            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher is waiting for message receiver process exit");

            rcvProcess.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver process worked");
            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher resources is disposing...");

            stream.Close();
            serMsgOwner.Dispose();
            rcvProcess.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher resources disposed");
            Console.WriteLine("Message publisher worked");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { PrintQuitMessageAndExit(ex.Message); }

        Pause();
    }
    void Pause(string? message = null)
    {
        const string defMsg = "Press any button...";

        Console.WriteLine(message ?? defMsg);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    void PrintQuitMessageAndExit(string? message = null, bool isError = true)
    {
        const string unknowErrMsg = "<unknow>";

        if (isError)
        {
            var tempFc = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            Console.Write("[ERROR]: ");
            Console.WriteLine(message ?? unknowErrMsg);

            Console.ForegroundColor = tempFc;
        }
        else if (message != null)
            Console.WriteLine(message);

        Pause();

        env.Exit(isError ? -1 : 0);
    }
}
```

*App.cs* (*MessageReceiver.csproj*)

```
using env = Environment;

sealed class App
{
    public string StreamHandle { get; }

    App(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid arg count", "args");

        StreamHandle = args[0]; // получаем дескриптор нашего потока
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) => new App(args).Run();
    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver is working...");
            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver resources is initializing...");

            using var stream = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(PipeDirection.In, StreamHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("Message receiver resources initialized");
            Console.WriteLine("Transmission started...");

            string msg;

            try
            {
                Span<byte> encodedBufferLengthBuffer = stackalloc byte[4];

                if (stream.Read(encodedBufferLengthBuffer) != 4) PrintQuitMessageAndExit("Transmission failed");

                var bufferLength = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(encodedBufferLengthBuffer);
                using var bufferOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferLength);
                var buffer = bufferOwner.Memory.Slice(0, bufferLength).Span; // Memory.Slice эффективнее, чем Span.Slice (ссылка #1,2)

                if (stream.Read(buffer) != bufferLength) PrintQuitMessageAndExit("Transmission failed");

                Console.WriteLine("Transmission completed");

                msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);

                Console.Write("Message: ");
                Console.WriteLine(msg);

                Console.WriteLine("Message receiver resources is disposing...");

                stream.Close();
                bufferOwner.Dispose();

                Console.WriteLine("Message receiver resources disposed");
                Console.WriteLine("Message receiver worked");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("connect", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            { PrintQuitMessageAndExit("Transmission aborted"); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { PrintQuitMessageAndExit(ex.Message); };

        Pause();
    }
    void Pause(string? message = null)
    {
        const string defMsg = "Press any button...";

        Console.WriteLine(message ?? defMsg);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    void PrintQuitMessageAndExit(string? message = null, bool isError = true)
    {
        const string unknowErrMsg = "<unknow>";

        if (isError)
        {
            var tempFc = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            Console.Write("[ERROR]: ");
            Console.WriteLine(message ?? unknowErrMsg);

            Console.ForegroundColor = tempFc;
        }
        else if (message != null)
            Console.WriteLine(message);

        Pause();

        env.Exit(isError ? -1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Премного благодарен. Попробую это как-нибудь упихнуть в основной проект.